# \Obeylines breaks Table

Tags: tables

My tablular insists on adding these two legs at the bottom, and I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\obeylines
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}\hline
   Sample&Replication&Fermentation\\
   \hline
   5   &   1   &   4\\\hline
   10  &   1   &   4\\\hline
   15  &   1   &   4\\\hline
   20  &   1   &   4\\\hline
   25  &   1   &   4\\\hline
   25  &   1   &   4\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you must have something between the last `\hline` and `\end{tabular}` but it is impossible to debug the code fragment shown, please post  small complete document that makes the image shown.

Comment: Thank you. I wouldn'tknow how what to post, because I'm working with a several hundred line document in several files. I can see, that if I post the above table code into an empty document, it works and does not add the legs. So something in my document is messing up the table. I will try to figure out how to post a version of my document.

Comment: start from a copy of your document, delete everything except that table, check the problem occurs, if so delete every package from the document preamble that you can delete while still showing the problem, then post the resulting small document...

Comment: Thank you for your help. In the editing process you described, I found out that the \obeylines command seems to ruin my tables. It works without it.

Comment: 99 times out of a 100 when you ask people to make an example, they solve the problem:-) yes `\obeylines` would have that effect, you could self answer, or delete the question, whichever you think is most useful to others

Comment: The \obeylines command will break the tables.

Comment: What's the reason for `\obeylines`? You're shooting your own foot.

Comment: It's a much bigger document. I'm copying content fourth and back from a word file, and it is helpful not having to add and remove the formatting.

Answer (score 6):

Use a `%` for the last line

```
    25      &   1           &   4\\\hline%
\end{tabular}
```

It is needed if you have used `\obeylines`. However, I can not see the sense of using this comamnd in the document.